# Azure DevOps SaaS - Unable to distinct group and team name in REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve only the groups of an organization , example for a project in `Project settings -> General -> Permissions` , I would like to retrieve only the Type as "Group" . When using the below REST API, I get the Type "Team" also .

Rest API used - `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{CollectionName}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=7.0-preview.1`

How can I get the groups alone instead of getting Team names also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, here is not a directly way to realize it. For even in UI if you go to organization settings->permission you could not directly see type 'Team'.

But here is an idea for your reference. For we get rest api [Groups - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)(return include Teams in the org and groups in the org) and rest api Teams - [Get All Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get-all-teams?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP), you could write your script to filter the Teams from the second rest api return from the first return one.

But if you do need the direct feature, we recommend that you can directly report the feature requests:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=22&entry=suggestion. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate engineering team and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Comment: Makes sense. A temporary solution is helpful, will open a request